# картинка в Button, изменение цвета

Tags: android, android-button, vector-drawable

в Button вставил векторную картинку в бэкграунд,но у картинки почему то изменены цвета, то есть ставил и прозрачность в векторном изображении и пробовал менять цвета, но ничего не меняется. Проблема решилась тем, что изменил Button на ImageButton, но тогда кнопка начала отличаться по форме от других кнопок и заливка картинки как будто имела ограничения. Но хотелось бы все таки оставить обычный Button, подскажите как изменять цвета в если изображение векторное.

Comment: ImageButton в помощь

Comment: @Style-7 спасибо за совет. Но в вопросе об ImageButton уже написано. Есть отличия по форме от обычных Button